# How to make a single Menu Item call another Mega Menu for Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus, sub-menu

I'm trying to build a hierarchical directory using custom post types and custom taxonomies as I've described in [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/183947/69888).

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to make those posts accessible from only a single menu item of my current primary navigation menu as Mega Menu to be popped up when I hover over that menu item. I don't prefer to use any Mega Menu Plugin to accomplish this task as my site's performance is much slowing down by using already too many plugins.

Instead, I prefer to use my custom mega drop down menu which will be built with CSS and jQuery or may be with Ajax as well.

The Sequence should be like,

**[Single Menu Item] >> [Mega Drop Down Menu]**

**Mega menu should contain both hierarchical and non-hierarchical taxonomies in several steps until I reach to my destination which is a single post that belongs to a specific custom post type.**

**But the most important fact is that before I reach to that post the way should be in multiple steps within that mega menu.**

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly:

set your permalink structure as `/%category%/%post%/`

and from your mega menu create custom links for taxonomies categories and single posts.

Comment: First of all, I'm actually concerned with the creation of the mega menu then I'd like to add menu items to it. Anyways, thanks buddy for your kind effort to answer my question.